# what is difference between "acr38 card tools" & "opensc"?

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I have uploaded a HelloWorld.cap file in a Javacard and sent some APDU commands via "acr38 card tool" software to the card and received **Helloworld!** in ASCII code as output. But when I sent same APDU commands with opensc-tool I received **Invalid arguments** in output instead of **HelloWorld!** 
What is the problem?

ACR38 card tool output:

```
< 00 A4 04 00 0B 00
< 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 66
> 610B

< 00 C0 00 00 00 0B
> 62 79 62 79 65 20 57 6F 72 6C 64
> 9000
```

Opensc-tool output:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSC Project\OpenSC\tools>opensc-tool.exe -s 00:a4:04:00:0b:0
1:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:00:66
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 66
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)

C:\Program Files\OpenSC Project\OpenSC\tools>opensc-tool.exe -s 00:c0:00:00:00:0
b
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 C0 00 00 00 0B
APDU transmit failed: Invalid arguments
```

Comment: your are obviously not even using the same APDUs? have you read about APDU structure?

Comment: @PaulBastian both are the same!

Comment: isnt there an additional zero after Lc in the first debug compared to the second??

Comment: No dear Paul,In **ACR38 Card tool**, it shows **Le** in the first line just after **Lc** . And in the second line, it shows the **data**. So there isn't any difference between them, And I think as Mr Micheal has said in the answer one 00 must remove from command in the Opensc-tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that opensc-tool implicitly resets the card on start. So the effect of the first command, i. e. selection of the application, is lost when sending the second command. I would try next, to specify the two commands in the same opensc-tool call.

Comment: How it is possible to send two commands in one opensc-tool call?!

Comment: @abraham I have no machine running it but would first try to add another -s "hh:hh:hh".

Comment: Oh! Good idea. I'll try it too.

Comment: I try **opensc-tool -s 00a404000a0102030405060708090066 -s 800000000b** and it works. So we should remove one of the 00 and  then send two command in one opensc-tool call.

Answer (score 1):

```
00 C0 00 00 00 0B
```

Is not a valid APDU. An ISO 7816-4 APDU (with 1 byte length fields) looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| CLA      | INS      | P1       | P2       | Lc       | DATA       | Le       |
| (1 byte) | (1 byte) | (1 byte) | (1 byte) | (1 byte) | (Nc bytes) | (1 byte) |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
```

`Lc` is only present if `Nc` (the length of the `DATA` field) is greater than 0 bytes. `Le` is only present if there is data expected in the response APDU.

As your APDU does not contain a `DATA` field, it must not have an `Lc` field. Thus either

```
00 C0 00 00 0B
```

(`INS` = `0xC0` and expected response length of 11 bytes) or

```
00 C0 00 00 00
```

(`INS` = `0xC0` and expected response length of 256 bytes) would be valid APDU commands that come close to your "APDU".

Comment: Although I removed one of the 00 of the command but it did not work until I send two command in one opensc-tool call and it worked.

Comment: @user3628920 Right, but that's to completely unrelated problems. The issue described in your question (resulting in the error "APDU transmit failed: Invalid arguments") is clearly caused by the additional byte. You should have received some other error message after fixing that (e.g. some status word other than 0x9000).

Comment: Yes, you right. I received **6D00** instead of **invalid arguments**